# Grails mapping to solve exception when saving instance

Tags: grails, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have the following domain classes:

```
class Team{   
    static hasMany = [localMatches: Match, visitingMatches: Match]
    static mappedBy = [localMatches: 'localTeam', visitingMatches: 'visitingTeam']

    List<Match> localMatches = new ArrayList<Match>()
    List<Match> visitingMatches = new ArrayList<Match>()
}

class Match{
    Team localTeam
    Team visitingTeam
}
```

When I run the following:

```
Match match = new Match(localTeam: aLocalTeam, visitingTeam: aVisitingTeam)
match.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

I get the exception "Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "LOCAL_TEAM_ID"; SQL statement:"

So I need to set the match in each team before saving the match to avoid the exception:

```
Match match = new Match(localTeam: aLocalTeam, visitingTeam: aVisitingTeam)
aLocalTeam.localMatches.add(match)
aVisitingTeam.localMatches.add(match)
match.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

Is there any way of mapping the classes so I wouldn't need to do add the match to each team before saving?

Answer (score 2):

The `hasMany` block defines that a `Match` has many `localMatches`, but then below redefines `localMatches` as a relationship to a single `Match`. What I believe you actually mean is:

```
class Team {   
    static hasMany = [localMatches: Match, visitingMatches: Match]
    static mappedBy = [localMatches: 'localTeam', visitingMatches: 'visitingTeam']
}

class Match {
    Team localTeam
    Team visitingTeam
}
```

Mapped this way, `Team` will have two collections of `Matches` and each `Match` will have a `local` and `visiting Team`.

Comment: Yes, I missed the example, now I've edited it. I always tend to declare de lists in an explicit way because otherwise I sometimes experiments extrange bugs when debugging on eclipe